# Cart Checkout problem in my Magento galabrand theme

Tags: checkout

I an new developer. I work with magento. Everything is ok but when i press cart checkout then show an error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 3200 bytes) in
>   /home/thebdmar/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/galabrandstore/template/page/html/head.phtml
>   on line 46

Please advice me .

I got a solution "memory_limit must be 64M or more." ----> this is currect.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your allocated memory is waaay to low for magento to function properly.
The minimum requirement is `256M` and the recommended value is `512M`.
[You can see here the system requirements.](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements)